# How to store and type last word of the displayed text using Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

How to store last word of the security question displayed on the screen and type it into the text field using Selenium IDE.

Question: What was the name of your first pet?
Answer will be: Pet

Question:   What was your childhood nickname that most people do not know?
Answer will be: know

Question: What was the first and last name of your first manager?
Answer will be: manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every security question you have,
use assertTextPresent and match the last word

ex:
assertTextPresent
target
pet

type
target textbox
Pet

assertTextPresent
target
knoe

type
target
Know

you have to make different test case for each question, together it will be a test suite for security question
this is in the case when you have limited question

Comment: So you are suggesting to use it in combination with goto label? These questions appearing in random order.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide sample HTML it will be better, but maybe in the page DOM after each question there is a **input** with corresponding labels? If not try with your own algorithm that will pair question-answer fields.

As to

> store last word

you ca try with **storeText** or **store** commands.